# Where should I ask questions about directing me to a solution, but with no code?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm trying to build a system of users and each user has its own username and password on my site. Now, on the user area I want to save some lists and so on, and I don't have any code for that right now.
I think it needs cookies, but I'm not sure.

Where on Stack Exchange can I ask about directions on building the right way to solve problems? I hope you understand me, if not, I will try to explain better.

Comment: I think on Google

Comment: Just use simple abstract keywords to google(keywords e.g. language you use; abstract e.g. "number" instead of "3451").

Comment: Google refered me to here, but i dont have the code for the specific user area that i want to creat, there for im asking if there is a site on the stack exchange network that helps direct people on the right way of building software.

Comment: I think that it will always closed for being too broad, so take @Rizier123 advice and try searching for abstract terms in your query to get to the right tutorials. It helped me when I started developing (So, you're not the only one :) )

Comment: @GrowingDev THANK YOU for checking first. Genuinely :). Now hopefully we can point you to the right way around your issue: follow Rizier's advice. Then once you hit a snag in one of these tutorials, that's when you turn to SO, with a very specific problem about that tutorial, what it should do, what it does instead, and what you did to try to get around it.  Stack is a tool for when you're far more advanced than where you are on your project right now.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! :) hope to see you at SO when i find what i need to ask. :)

Comment: So, you know nothing, and want to know how to know a lot of things.  Hmmm...  First, you have to pick a programming language and framework.  From there, you need to read up on the syntax and parts of the framework.  Once you've identified the web components of the framework, you need to learn how they work to produce a website.  Once you know how to do that you need to learn how authentication works in the web parts of the framework.  You'll probably have several options, so you need to learn them and choose the best one.  Once you've done ALL OF THIS, you can sit down and start typing.

Comment: There's this question and answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398280/1315009 related to no-code. I've made a proposal in the comment to gather community to open a request on area51 for opening a nocode site in stack-exchange. Please upvote there in my comment if you are interested and follow that question so we'll update soon.