# How can a user show "code" on a visual tool?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76368284/1107226), the OP is using an automated tool - one that records actions and then can be adjusted. There is no "code" to be provided. Yet, it has been closed, requesting a minimal, reproducible code example.

The OP has provided images of the error message they're receiving and a screen having to do with the UI elements in question. They also have provided a description of what they're trying to do, along with an explanation of the basic way the tool works (it selects elements starting from the upper left corner).

The OP has tagged the question appropriately, as in matching the [tool they are using (Microsoft Power Automate)](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/) - which, again, doesn't use "code".

The issue the OP is having is presented in a number of places on the web - but without a specific explanation of how to fix it (outside of editing the element tree - which the OP has included a basic image of). [One example is on this *Power Automate* website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/test-selectors): scroll down to **Multiple UI elements found**, and it explains the OP's issue - including a screen similar to what the OP included in their question. However, no image or instructions are given to *fix* the issue.

I suspect the "close" voters don't have an understanding of the tool in question; therefore, they voted to close for lack of a "minimal, reproducible code example". Since this tool doesn't use "code", there's no way to give a "code" example.

What else is necessary - for people who might understand the actual VISUAL tool in question - for the OP to add to the question to get it re-opened and answered?

Comment: this doesn't appear to be programming related.

Comment: @KevinB, automation tools are still programming-related - they just do the programming for you. Also, `power-automate` and `power-automate-desktop` are clearly valid tags on SO, so others are asking/answering questions about this topic.

Comment: A tag existing for a tool doesn't greenlight every question one may have about said tool.

Comment: @KevinB: true, tags don't mean the question has quality; but it does mean that it's SO-able. Otherwise, the tags would've been burninated.

Comment: that's not strictly true. We have financial tags on SO for example, for tools related to the handling of billing apis for AWS. that doesn't make questions about AWS Billing on topic.

Comment: @KevinB, the question is about the tool - not what they're automating with the tool, so that response also doesn't apply.

Comment: Tags literally mean nothing as far as whether a question is on-topic. We have people posting (obviously off-topic) advanced math questions with the math tag, and yet it's still appropriate to have a math tag.

Comment: Again, @PresidentJamesK.Polk: yes, there are tags that can promote off-topic questions; however, in this case they're specifically asking about the tool and how it works - not anything outside of the tool.

Comment: Tag links: [tag:power-automate] and [tag:power-automate-desktop]

Comment: @KevinB Power Automate uses JSON so any questions about that at least should be on-topic.

Comment: "*Visual Tool*" with "*low-code*"/"*no code*"/whatever, closing that Question on 'SO-Main' as "Needs details or clarity" is a no-brainer as the Error Msg (or "*Explanation*" like the Asker had called it) is still posted as Image-only and is therefore not searchable and won't help any future Users as all Search-Keywords are (only) contained in that Error Msg. (And the Asker didn't follow up at all...)

Comment: @chivracq: Had that been explained to the user, or their post edited to correct that issue... the OP did attempt to clarify based on a suggestion I gave. I didn't think to suggest changing the image to text, and seemingly everyone else was busy downvoting and close voting to give this first-time poster any kind assistance.

Comment: Well, it's the Asker's *responsibility* to read the 'Tour' and the 'How to ask' Help-pages, one User actually posted a [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76368284/#comment134677675_76368284) about Code/Error Msg as Image, and they also did quite some Editing on the Qt, ... but they were not going to re-type the Content of that Screenshot/Error Msg, the Asker has to do that themselves... (And you also have 8k-Rep, I would "expect" you to "know" that yourself...)

Comment: @chivracq: no individual is perfect, and no individual necessarily gets things "right" the very first time. How to treat first-time posters has been discussed many times. SO even has a banner on the question, reminding people that this is a first time poster, so please be patient with them. Yet, the apparent joy of attacking with downvotes and close-votes - especially without explanation -  just can't seem to be overcome.

Comment: Hum, 1 or 2 more thing(s), oh...!, yep indeed, I withdraw my "no Follow-up at all", I had not checked the 'Timeline'..., only the Comments... // But something "a bit strange", is that that Qt actually came from the 'Staging Ground', and the "Code/Error as Image" should have been *caught* and addressed in the 'Staging Ground' already, this is one of the main purposes of the SG, about Question Quality...

Comment: @chivracq from the staging ground post (which requires access to the SG to view): "The question has been automatically published. The question could not be reviewed in time. It’s been publicly posted and is now open to votes and answers."

Comment: Ah...!?, alright @RyanM, that explains *it* then, a bit more precisely than "*Graduated*", ... which doesn't mean much and gets used on 'SO'/'SE' in all flavours..., as 'Related Questions using ML' get *[graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424716/)*, 'Change the Voting Buttons' also get *[graduated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359/642998)*, and so on...

Answer (score 16):

First, I should say that I don't think questions about this tool are *inherently* off-topic for Stack Overflow; if that were that case, I would have used the "Not about programming" close reason but, in this case, I used "needs details or clarity" … because that was (and still *is*) my opinion about the question. (However, the reason shown in the blue banner doesn't necessarily reflect each individual close reason.) I am also prepared to accept that my decision *may* have been wrong – I do a lot of reviews each day and this was one of them; although I am not a so-called "robo-reviewer", I do make mistakes from time to time.

So, for some more information on my decision and responses to the question raised here:

> *The OP has provided images of the error message they're receiving and a screen having to do with the UI elements in question.*

Not really. There doesn't appear to be an "error message", just not the desired behaviour: i.e. text going into the wrong UI element(s). A screenshot of the application with the desired and actual text boxes highlighted would be useful.

> *What else is necessary - for people who might understand the actual VISUAL tool in question - for the OP to add to the question to get it
> re-opened and answered?*

I freely accept that I am no "expert" in this subject but I felt sufficiently confident (again, perhaps incorrectly) that more information about the nature of the UI elements and their relative positions is needed for an authoritative answer to be provided. Can you (the poster of this Meta question) provided a *definitive* answer for the OP with the limited information given?

---

Also, I am not one of the downvoters (either of the original question or the Meta one). A downvote (IMHO) implies lack of effort on the part of the poster, which I don't think is the case, here. That "Meta Effect" can be an unpleasant experience – especially for new users – and I do not wish to be associated with it in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your close vote on the original question, Adrian. Yes, I could have provided an answer with the amount of information given - had I known how to edit UI elements in Power Automate Desktop. Again, this is an issue that is described in several places on the web. The first image the OP posted was of the error message - as described in Microsoft documentation for the product (see link in my question). The OP is trying to record steps to automate a task in an app. They possibly could've provided a video of their actions, but it's not pertinent to the solution.

Comment: For clarity, I say "not pertinent to the solution" because the solution is to edit the UI element. This would be done starting in the window in the OP's 2nd image; however, the next steps are what the OP needs.

Answer (score 5):

Power Automate and Power Automate Desktop are what are called "*no or low-code tools*".

According to the meta conversation *[Where and how can I ask questions related to no-code tools like Webflow and Squarespace?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398279/1107226)*, no-code tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and low-code tools *can* be off-topic *if the question isn't code-specific*.

Power Automate and Power Automate Desktop do allow small amounts of code to be used, similar to [Webflow, as described in this answer to the above question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398280/1107226).

As a result,
**if** the user's issue with these tools ***involves code***
**then** the question can be considered on-topic for Stack Overflow
**and**
the tags [power-automate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-automate) and [power-automate-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/power-automate-desktop) would be appropriate.

Comment: Wait, who says "low code" is off-topic? Low code is still code, is it not? If Low code is off-topic then Excel formulas sure as hell are, too. The post you linked to is only about _no_ code tools. Please edit your post to reflect that fact.

Comment: @TylerH: I said "do ... allow small amounts of code..." and "*if*..." which all cover "low code" tools as well. The tools, in particular, are off-topic **unless** "the user can post reproducible code associated with their issue"

Comment: You also said "Power Automate and Power Automate Desktop are what's called "no or low-code tools. According to the meta conversation Where and how can I ask questions related to no-code tools like Webflow and Squarespace?, **that makes them off-topic for Stack Overflow.**" But low-code tools are _not_ off-topic for Stack Overflow according to that meta conversation.

Comment: Okay, then, @TylerH: **please find me a link that discusses *only* low-code tools, and I'll be happy to add it**. I was not able to find one. I found two blog entries *at Stack Overflow Blog* that discuss the rise and usefulness of "no or low-code tools", yet SO *community* doesn't even allow those tools to be discussed unless the question is specific to code. Had I been able to find other references EASILY, I wouldn't have posted my question; and SOMEONE would've KINDLY informed the FIRST TIME POSTER that their question was off-topic instead of simply closing it with no further explanation

Comment: No need to start a tirade about a mere factual inaccuracy in a post. Here, I'll fix the issue for you.

Comment: @TylerH: The first time poster was attacked with multiple downvotes with no explanation. In trying to find a simple answer to why a perfectly valid "visual" tool question was attacked, I too was attacked with multiple downvotes and no explanation whatsoever that code was a required feature of an SO question. I have answered questions on a financial tool myself and totally understand that there are in-bounds and out-of-bounds questions for those. That *did not* explain the answer to my question. Now, you are attacking me on the wording of my answer. Tirade? Yeah. Example of how SO sucks.

Comment: Yeah, if you write something that is wrong people tend to point that out. That's the internet. It's not "attacking you", it's an attempt to correct the information. See how easy it was to edit the answer here to make it correct? Instead of leaving long comments about how SO sucks or you are being attacked, instead just edit the post when someone provides feedback that it needs to be edited.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to attempt to answer the question you've asked.

Comment: @Makyen: since I'm not getting any real, clear answers - only criticism of my question - this is my best guess. Several people have made comments about tags; however, the tags aren't why the question was closed. If, indeed, a no-code question is off-topic in SO, then this is a valid answer.

Comment: @leanne But, how does this answer 'How can a user show "code" on a visual tool?' That's the question you've asked in this Q&A. It's very specific. It's focused. You haven't, at all, asked the more general question "Are no or low-code tools generally on-topic on Stack Overflow?", which is the question you're answering in this answer.

Comment: @Makyen: I further clarified the title question with the body text "*What else is necessary ... for the OP to add to the question to get it re-opened and answered?*" Basically, the answer to that was that since this is a no-code situation, the question would be off-topic, and therefore non-re-openable. There is no answer to my title question, as 1) it's not possible to show code on a no-code tool, and 2) the original question would seem to be off-topic because one can't show code on a no-code tool. You could say the title question was rhetorical, with the body question being the real one.

Comment: @Makyen: and, as you can see, all of the comments and provided "answers" in this thread relate to that body question, not directly to the title.

Comment: Your subsequent edits of the answer introduce redundant information and harm readability.

Comment: @TylerH: example(s) please? Eg, what is redundant? What is difficult to read?

Comment: The final paragraph already states if the question involves code that it is OK. Low-code tools are (like _any other question_) off-topic if they aren't about coding... there's no need to reiterate that; SO is a _coding_ Q&A site. As for difficult reading, the grammatically incorrect, non-standard newlines with bolding are hard to read compared to natural (grammatically correct) sentence structure.

Comment: @TylerH: I agree with the non-standard newlines and bolding. There, I was making a point by using an `if/then` type structure. I thought it was humorous, but I'll be happy to put it back to *your* style, if you prefer. The reiteration was because, as I noted in my original version, the linked thread discusses *both* no- and low-code situations. However, you didn't seem to understand that and wanted to limit my wording to no-code situations. I reiterated to clarify that the linked thread does, indeed, cover both situations.

Comment: @TylerH: to remind you of why you wanted my post edited in the first place, from your original comment above: "*The post you linked to is only about no code tools. Please edit your post to reflect that fact.*" The linked post, again, is *not* in fact "only about no code tools".

Answer (score 1):

A question is on-topic if it is about programming (in a broad sense; that there's a tool involved doesn't invalidate it) and *it can be answered definitely.* I suspect that the latter would be true in this case... if the question was asked more clearly. That typically (but not universally) involves a key set of information:

1. What are you using?
2. What is wrong?
3. How did you get there?
4. What have you tried to fix it so far?

My impression from this question is that they're saying what tool they're using but haven't really clearly indicated what is wrong and I don't understand what they've done to try to fix it (but then I've never used that tool so I'm not a good judge). As such, it feels unanswerable and I broadly agree with the close: details needed so that it is possible for someone to help.

Comment: Again, someone who *is* familiar with the tool would have been able to answer with the information provided. As I noted in my question, people unfamiliar with the tool wouldn't know. And, it was closed so quickly, with multiple downvotes immediately - *and not a single comment of explanation, and a close reason requiring code that can't be provided for this tool* - and all of this rudeness for a first-time poster.

Comment: To answer your bullets, if you knew the tool: 1) Power Automate Desktop; 2) Multiple UI controls have been matched; the tool is selecting the first one from the upper left corner rather than the one the OP wants; 3) Using the recorder, the OP performed steps they wanted automated, however a particular textbox (UI control) is not being matched when tested; 4) the OP edited the UI element tree (2nd image), which did cause different textboxes to match, but not the one they wanted. All 4 questions answered, as thoroughly as needed. The solution is: how to edit the element tree to match correctly.